# Cleaning `sort -nr` result to CSV format in terminal

Tags: sorting, unix, csv

I have a file that is a result from `sort -nr` command

```
  10000 a, b, c, d
    110 c, d, e, f
     11 e, f, e, d
```

it's from a file that contains a lot of lines like below

```
a, b, c, d
a, b, c, d
a, b, c, d
a, b, c, d
a, b, c, d
c, d, e, f
e, f, e, d
```

and then applied with this command  `cat file | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`. (I hope you get the picture).

I want to change the result to

```
10000, a, b, c, d
110, c, d, e, f
11, e, f, e, d
```

I'm looking for a one liner unix command to clean the space padding in the front and change the first space to comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you just use `awk` like this?

```
$ awk '{a[$0]++} END{for (i in a) print a[i], i}' a | sort -nr
5 a, b, c, d
1 e, f, e, d
1 c, d, e, f
```

This way you can indicate the separator between the counter and the lines itself:

```
$ awk '{a[$0]++} END{for (i in a) print a[i], i}' OFS="->" a | sort -nr
5->a, b, c, d                                     ^^^^^^^^
1->e, f, e, d
1->c, d, e, f
```

#### Explanation

- `{a[$0]++}` for every single line (`$0`), keep track of how many times it has appeared. This is done with the array `a[]` that contains `a[line]=times`.
- `END{for (i in a) print a[i], i}` once you are done of processing the file, print the counter + line.
- `OFS="whatever"` indicates what field separator applies. When using `print`, in this case.

---

In case you want to use `sort` anyway, do use `sed` to perform the change:

```
$ sort a | uniq -c | sort -nr | sed -r 's/^[ ]*([0-9]*) /\1 -> /' 
5 -> a, b, c, d
1 -> e, f, e, d
1 -> c, d, e, f
```

This catches the first block of digits after the leading spaces and writes it back together with `->`.

Comment: i don't need to differentiate between the counter and the lines actually. tried your code but it's not working. your second code does give '->' though.
i don't need to recount the lines, just want to modify the results. but i will use your script next time.

Comment: Strange... What do you get as output? See also the update with a `sed` approach.

Comment: the sed works fine! thanks! the output for the first code was
1 -> 10000 a, b, c, d
1 ->   110 c, d, e, f
1 ->   11 e, f, e, d

Comment: I just used the `sed -r 's/^[ ]*([0-9]*) /\1 -> /'` anyway, thanks.

Comment: Ops, my fault! What I missed is to pipe to `sort -nr` :)